# Silverstripe 3 - send email with data of foreach-loop

Tags: email, foreach, silverstripe

I want to send an email with the data of a foreach loop but I don't know how to get the data into the email body.

that's my current code

```
...
...

    foreach($cartItems as $cartItem) {
        '<strong>' . $cartItem->Amount . 'x ' . $cartItem->Title . '</strong>' . '<span>' . $cartItem->Price . ' €/St. insgesamt ' . $cartItem->Sum . '</span><br>';
    }
...
...
    $messageBody = " 
         foreach() Content should be here
    "; 
    $email->setBody($messageBody);
...
...
```

can someone help me?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built in [Silverstripe Email](http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/topics/email) functionality to take advantage of Silverstripe's templating with your email.

With Silverstripe you can create a template for your email and populate it with whatever data you like.

Within your send function in your controller you can set the template with `setTemplate` and push data into the email template with `populateTemplate`:

```
$email = new Email($from, $to, $subject);

$email->setTemplate('EmailTemplate');

$email->populateTemplate(array(
    'CartItems' => $cartItems,
    'PageTitle' => $this->Title
));

$email->send();
```

Note that `$cartItems` has to be a `ArrayList` or `DataList` to be able to use `<% loop %>` in template. If `$cartItems` is an array, read how to convert it to `ArrayList` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12076288/1119263).

Put your template into `themes/mytheme/templates/Email/EmailTemplate.ss`

**EmailTemplate.ss**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    ...
    <% if $CartItems %>
    <% loop $CartItems %>
    ...
    <% end_loop %>
    <% end_if %>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Zauberfisch. I added your comments in. Sorry the community didn't approve it. I appreciate the improvement.